# how to reduce a map to get a pair or entry

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a map ,the Integer stands for the frequency and the Set stands for a Set of words ,Now I want to reduce this map to get the frequency of the set with the most words ,and the return the frequency and the number of words in that Set with a pair

```java
 public static Map<Integer, Set<String>> getCounts(In in)
```

My instinct tells me this is ok, this is what I think :

1. initial
2. Compare each word set separately,once the sum of words in a Set greater than the previous recorded, Update the pair
3. get the pair

but I get stuck as soon as I start ....

```java
 var temp = new Pair<Integer,Integer>(0, 0);
        Stream.of(wordCounts)
                .reduce()
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you might want to think about what you want to output when the map is empty.

You can use the convenient `max` method on streams

```
var pair = wordCounts.entrySet().stream()
    .map(x -> new Pair<>(x.getKey(), x.getValue().size()))
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getSecond));
```

This gives you an optional pair. The optional will be empty when the map is empty.

If you really want to use `reduce`, you can. Just change the `max` call to:

```
.reduce((a, b) -> a.getSecond() >= b.getSecond() ? a : b);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood this correctly:

```
map.entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getValue().size()))
        .map(x -> new Map.entry(x.getKey(), x.getValue().size()))
        .orElse(new Map.entry(0, 0));
```

Comment: yep,that's really helpful.Thanks a lot ,but I changed a little ,IDEA show me can't resolve symbol `entry` ,so I change the `Map.entry` to Pair ,and this work well

Comment: @Cyberlin `Map.entry` exists since jdk-9, indeed. But should be trivial to replace with a `Pair`

Comment: @Cyberlin you could [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)